# what is releation between Bolded text and "our capacity to..."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

According to Jim Whitman, ‘**the weight of evidence is that** our capacity to produce unwanted and sometimes dangerous conditions on a global scale is running greatly in excess of our deliberative and control mechanisms’.
Human societies are ‘manufacturing’ new global security risks at a faster rate than existing institutions can cope.

what he wants to say? does he wants to say that our dangerous capacity is more than our deliberative capacity for world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For understanding sentences like this, it's often helpful to split it into clauses and parse them individually:

> **The weight of evidence** (the measure of evidence on each side of an issue)
>
> **is that** (about to explain what the weight of evidence is, or in other words which side of it is "heavier")
>
> **our capacity to produce unwanted and sometimes dangerous conditions on a global scale** (the human race's ability to create conditions for itself, worldwide, which are neither wanted nor safe)
>
> **is running greatly in excess of** (is currently a lot greater than what follows)
>
> **our deliberative and control mechanisms.** (our ability to discuss issues or control the situation)

So yes, he's saying that our capacity for self-destruction outweighs our ability to prevent the world from going to hell in a handbasket via mature discussion and controlling the situation.